# How to get currently running raw id in Mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In android **MediaPlayer** we can create an Object like `MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this, R.raw.sound);`

But my question is what if I want to get this **raw id** in somewhere else in my activity. Is it possible ? If so how?

I search for it but could not reach any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from activity

```
int sound_file_id =  getResources().getIdentifier("sound","raw" ,getPackageName());
```

from fragment

```
int sound_file_id =  getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("sound","raw" ,getActivity().getPackageName());
```

hope this answers your question

Comment: this brings me certain raw id. actually my purpose is; I created 1 MediaPlayer object and wanna learn which sound is playing currently.

Comment: one idea I have in mind now and you may find it useful is to load the media player from a variable, reassign the variable with new files before passing to MP,and if you want to read what file is currently running, you just read the variable. in such case variable will always reflect currently running file.

Comment: Yea this is really simple and solves my problem! thank you and I am accepting your answer!